# Integrating $3^{2x}$ ($\int 3^{2x} dx $)

Tags: integration, substitution

I am tring to integrate the following: $3^{2x}$

My working has been shown as the following

$$\int 3^{2x} dx $$

I used the substitution $u = 2x$, so

$$\frac{du}{2} = dx $$

hence

$$\int 3^{2x} dx = \int 3^{u} \frac{du}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\int 3^{u} du $$

However, I can't go any further.

From this, I can't seem to prove the general result of  $\int a^{x} dx $ either.

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: How would you express $u\mapsto 3^u$ using the usual exponential fonction?

Comment: Use the fact that $\frac{\partial e^x}{\partial x}=e^x$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $3^{2x} = 9^x$, so you are basically back to square one.

Next, note that $9^x = e^{x \ln 9}$. To see this :
$$
e^{x \ln 9} = (e^{\ln 9})^x = 9^x
$$

Hence, 
$$
\int 3^{2x} dx = \int 9^x dx = \int e^{x \ln 9} dx 
$$
Now, let $y = x  \ln 9$,  so that  $dy = (\ln 9) dx$.
$$
\int e^{x \ln 9} dx = \int e^y \frac {dy}{\ln 9} = \frac{e^y}{\ln 9} + C = \frac{9^x}{\ln 9} + C
$$

It's worth noticing that the derivative is the same as the original function up to a constant ($\frac 1{\ln 9}$) and the constant of integration.

Comment: Nice! Makes absolutely perfect sense. Got it! Upvoted! Upvote my post please if it helps other people, and have a nice day!

Comment: Upvoted, please have a good day sir.

Comment: You forgot your +C as well for the final steps in the integration, since the integral does not have limits! :)

Comment: Good point. Thank you for the point out.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\displaystyle\int{a^{mx}}\ dx=\dfrac{a^{mx}}{m\cdot\ln a}+c$

Answer (score 0):

Formula -

$$\int a^x = \frac{a^x}{\ln a} + c$$

Now we have,

$$\frac{1}{2}\int 3^{u} du $$

$$=  \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3^u}{\ln 3} + c$$

$$=  \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3^{2x}}{\ln 3} + c$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$
D3^{u} = D(\exp (u\log 3)) = \exp(u\log 3)\cdot \log 3 = 3^{u}\log 3.
$$
So 
$$
\int 3^{u} = \int \frac{D3^{u}}{\log 3} = \frac{3^{u}}{\log 3} + \text{constant}.
$$